# canvasに対するeffect:explodeが反映されない

Tags: jquery, html5, jquery-ui

下記の様に、canvasにexplodeのアニメーションをかけたところ、動作しません。

```
$("#my_canvas").effect("explode", {} ,200);
```

こちらはOK

```
$("#my_canvas").effect("bounce", {} ,200);
```

canvasにかけられるアニメーションとかけられないアニメーションがあるのでしょうか？

追記：
私の環境では下記のコードを実行すると、アニメーションせずにただ画像が消えます。
実行環境はmacのchromeです。

読み込み

```
$canvas = $("<canvas></canvas>").appendTo("body").width(500).height(500);
var ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // Or at whatever offset you like
};
img.src = "https://www.google.co.jp/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
```

イメージロード後にアニメーション実行

```
$canvas.effect("explode",{},500);
```

Comment: 私の環境だとどちらのアニメーションも動きますね... (OSX+ Chrome40/Opera26/FireFox35)

Comment: @Taizan_Yonetuji さん。 Windows でも、 Chrome for Android でも、二つのエフェクトが効きます... 該当の動かないコードはありますか？

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/40v5qm8r/2/ テストコードを作って見ました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<canvas>` 要素を分割表示するときに描画内容が消えてしまっているようです。 `<canvas>` 自体には、 explode エフェクトはかかっています。

ちょっと汚いですが、`<canvas>` を一旦 `<img>` に変えてからスワップしてエフェクトをかけてみると、それっぽく実現できました。

以下サンプルを示します。

```js
var canvas = $("#my_canvas");
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
var image = $("#image");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(30, 96);
ctx.lineTo(70, 66);
ctx.lineTo(103, 76);
ctx.lineTo(170, 15);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.drawImage(image[0], 0, 0, 158, 158);
var my_image = $("#my_image");
my_image.hide();

function explodeCanvas() {
    var my_canvas = $("#my_canvas");
    var my_image = $("#my_image");
    try {
      my_image[0].src = my_canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
      my_canvas.hide();
      my_image.show();
      my_image.hide('explode',{pieces: 64},500);
    } catch ( e) {
      alert( e); // Canvas の汚れ方でセキュリティエラーが出る
    }
}
```

```css
#my_canvas { background-color: lightblue; }
.stage { height:160px; background-color: lightgray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
1.Canvas:
<button onclick="$('#my_canvas').effect('explode',{},500);">explode(fail)</button>
<button onclick="$('#my_canvas').effect('bounce',{},500);">bounce</button>
<button onclick="$('#my_canvas').toggle('explode',{pieces: 64},500);">toggle.explode(fail)</button>
<button onclick="explodeCanvas()">convert &amp; explode &amp; hide</button>
<hr />
<div class="stage">
    <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
    <img id="my_image" height="158" />
</div>
<hr />
2. Image:
<button onclick="$('#image').effect('explode',{},500);">explode</button>
<button onclick="$('#image').effect('bounce',{},500);">bounce</button>
<button onclick="$('#image').toggle('explode',{pieces: 64},500);">toggle.explode</button>
<hr />
<div class="stage">
<img id="image" width="158" height="158" title="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
</div>
```

※ 注意点は、別ドメインのイメージを描画した後だと、 SecurityException が出るブラウザがあることです。(おそらく WebKit 系が問題)。例はイメージ埋め込みです。

Comment: canvasで落書きしてからeffectを選択してかけられる機能をつくっていたんですが、一端imgに変換して実行しないと駄目そうですね

Comment: @Taizan_Yonetuji できました。SecurityException だけ気をつければ実用になりそうです。