# DOMを画像に書き出す方法

Tags: html

描画しているDOMを画像へと書き出すにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
具体的には下記のようなhtmlを丸ごと一枚の画像にしたいという場合です。
処理はサーバ側、クライアント側を問いません。

```
<entry><img src="1"/> <p>test</p> </entry>
<entry><img src="2"/> <p>test1</p> </entry> 
<entry><img src="3"/> <p>test2</p> </entry>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/5811/4978)にも書きましたが、「指定の HTML 要素を Canvas に描画して、それを画像データに変換すること」でいけます。

さすがに2回目なので、なにか [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) ライブラリを使用して、動くサンプルコード書きますね。

以下のコードでは、「Take a shot」 ボタンを押すと、画像の生成と、ダウンロードボタンを生成します。

```js
function screenshot( selector) {
    var element = $(selector)[0];
    html2canvas(element, { onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
        $('#screen_image')[0].src = imgData;
        $('#download')[0].href = imgData;
        $('#download')[0].innerHTML = "Download";
    }});
}

function erase_screenshot() {
    $('#screen_image')[0].src = "";
    $('#download')[0].href = "#";
    $('#download')[0].innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div>
  <button onclick="screenshot('#target_screen')">Take a shot</button>
  <button onclick="erase_screenshot()">Clear</button>
</div>
<hr />
<b>DOM:</b>
<div id="target_screen">
  <input type="text" value="abcdefghijklmn" /> 
  <entry><img src=""/>test</entry>
  <entry><img src=""/>test1</entry> 
  <entry><img src=""/>test2</entry> 
</div>
<hr />
<b>Image:</b>
<div id="output_screen">
  <img id="screen_image">
</div>
<hr />
<a id="download" href="#" download="test.png"></a>
```

サーバで行う場合は、 `screenshot()` 関数中の `imgData` が文字列になっていますのでサーバ側にそのまま POST してください。サーバ側で受け取った文字列を Base64 でデコードすることで、画像ファイルの生成完了となります。

**追記**: (2/6)

コメントしてくださった中の、「 *overflow:hidden な div の中に rotation がかかった要素* 」についてですが、問題点が抽出できなかったので、とりあえず、以下にサンプルを置いておきます。

**追記**: (2/7)

コメントの「 *overflow:hidden な div の中に rotation がかかった要素* 」について。おそらく、ですが、画像ファイルのの入手先が同じドメインである必要があります。別のドメインの画像が canvas に描かれている場合は、 DataURL に変換できません。具体的には、canvas2html の内部で SecurityException が起こっている可能性があります。これは、[こちらの回答『canvasに対するeffect:explodeが反映されない』](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5514/canvas%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%99%E3%82%8Beffectexplode%E3%81%8C%E5%8F%8D%E6%98%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/5599#5599)で、外部画像が使えないと伝えたことと同じです。

```js
function screenshot( selector) {
    var element = $(selector)[0];
    html2canvas(element, { onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
        $('#screen_image')[0].src = imgData;
        $('#download')[0].href = imgData;
        $('#download')[0].innerHTML = "Download";
    }});
}

function erase_screenshot() {
    $('#screen_image')[0].src = "";
    $('#download')[0].href = "#";
    $('#download')[0].innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
#target_screen, #output_screen {
  height: 180px;
}

.text_holder {
  height: 180px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.rotate10 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
            transform: rotate(10deg);
            transform-origin: 0 center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div>
  <button onclick="screenshot('#target_screen')">Take a shot</button>
  <button onclick="erase_screenshot()">Clear</button>
</div>
<hr />
<b>DOM:</b>
<div id="target_screen">
  <div class="text_holder">
    <div class="rotate10">[[Helloooow. I see the world tilt a bit.]]</div>

    <img class="rotate10" width="158" height="158" title="Stack Overflow" alt="Stack Overflow" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<b>Image:</b>
<div id="output_screen">
  <img id="screen_image">
</div>
<hr />
<a id="download" href="#" download="test.png"></a>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ただ使用していると１点問題があり、overflow:hiddenなdivの中にrotationがかかった要素がある場合に、overflowの判定後に回転してしまう事がわかりました。

Comment: すみません。上記の問題はimg要素にておきます

Comment: 本当ですね。画像は描画されていませんし、エラーログも出ていません。原因はわかりませんが、とりあえず、[埋め込み画像](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1629/4978)にすると動きました（回答のスニペットも変更済です）。おそらくこれは「画像ファイルががページと同じドメインから入手されたもの」である必要があります。以前の回答をする際に、別ドメインの画像を使うと `toDataURL()` から SecurityException が出ることがわかっています。

Comment: 検討ありがとうございます。上記の状態で、overflow:hiddenで画像が途切れていると、回転してから画像を切り出すべき部分が、切り出してから回転された形になってしまいます。上げてくださったスニペットでサイズを120くらいにすると再現するかと思います。おそらくライブラリの処理順の問題なので、おとなしくサーバ側でレンダリングする方式に切り替えようかと考えだしています。

Answer (score 0):

html2canvasを用いた実装を行ったのですが、下記の問題の解決が難しそうでした。
 - overflow:hiddenとrotationを組み合わせた時のレンダリングがおかしい
 - cssで縦書きにしたところ、一部の文字だけ横文字のまま

なので、サーバー側でphantomjsを用いる方式を試しました。
キャプチャしたい特定のDOMのみをレンダリングするページを作っておき、
[screenshot-as-a-service](https://github.com/fzaninotto/screenshot-as-a-service)というライブラリを用いて、渡したurlのキャプチャを取る方式です。

screenshot-as-a-serviceをダンロードしたディレクトリで

```
npm install
node app
```

その後、ターゲットのURLに対して下記の様なコマンドを実行すれば保存できます。

```
curl http://localhost:3000/?url=exapmle.com/target_dom > output.png
```

rubyから呼ぶ場合は

```
def save_img( path , url )    
  command = 'curl http://localhost:2000/?url='+url + ' > ' + path.to_s
  system( command )
end
```

この方法の場合、レンダリング順の問題は解決しましたが、残念ながらcssの縦書き対応については、配置は縦ですが文字は全て横のまま、とむしろ悪化しました。

（PhantomJSをきちんと勉強すればもっと直接キャプチャを呼べるとは思います