# html要素のアニメーションをgifとしてキャプチャしたい

Tags: html, jquery

htmlのある要素をcanvasに書き出しそれをサーバへpostする処理はhtml2canvas.jsを用いて可能になっています。
この時htmlにアニメーションがあった場合は、アニメーションgifとしてpostしたいと考えていますが、可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! が MIT ライセンスで公開している、 [gifshot](https://github.com/yahoo/gifshot) という軽量なライブラリを使うと、ウェブページ上でアニメーション GIF 画像の生成ができます。ただ、これは、「画像要素」もしくは「ビデオ要素」用に作られており、HTML をそのまま取り込むことはできませんので、工夫する必要がありそうです。

... まあ、[前回の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5851/)を応用すればできそうですね。連続して DOM 要素のスクリーンショットを取りつつ、画像データを [gifshot](https://github.com/yahoo/gifshot) に放り込む感じです。とりあえず、作ってみました。

以下のスニペットで、 "Add a screenshot as a new frame" ボタンを押すと、[`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) で撮影したスクリーンショットを新しいフレームとして、アニメーションGIFを、オンメモリで生成します。前回同様 Download リンクも用意しています。

質問中では、 `<html>` 要素のアニメーションを取られたいとのことですが、スクリーンショットの対象となる DOM 要素を `<body>` にすることで技術的には可能だと思われます。ただし、メモリの制約にはくれぐれも気をつけるようにしてください。

```js
var images = [];

function appendScreenshotFrame( selector) {
    var element = $(selector)[0];
    html2canvas(element, { onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
        images.push(imgData);
        createAnimationGIF(images);
    }});
}

function erase_screenshot() {
    $('#screen_image')[0].src = "";
    $('#download')[0].href = "#";
    $('#download')[0].innerHTML = "";
    images = [];
}

function createAnimationGIF( images) {
  gifshot.createGIF({
      gifWidth: 400,
      gifHeight: 25,
      images: images,
      interval: 0.2,
      text: 'フレーム数' + images.length,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontColor: '#ff2700',
      sampleInterval: 12
  }, function (obj) {
      if (!obj.error) {
          var image = obj.image;
          $('#screen_image')[0].src = image;
          $('#download')[0].href = image;
          $('#download')[0].innerHTML = "Download GIF";
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="http://yahoo.github.io/gifshot/js/dependencies/gifshot.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button onclick="appendScreenshotFrame('#target_screen')">Add a screenshot as a new frame</button>
  <button onclick="erase_screenshot()">Clear</button>
</div>
<hr />
<b>Source DOM:</b>
<div id="target_screen" style="width: 400px; height:25px;">
  <input type="text" style="width: 394px;"
         value="■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■□■" /> 
</div>
<hr />
<b>Generated Image:</b>
<div id="output_screen">
  <img id="screen_image">
</div>
<hr />
<a id="download" href="#" download="test_anim.gif"></a>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。タイマーで連続で取って試してみます