# html2canvasでキャプチャした画像が空になる

Tags: javascript, php, html5, html5-canvas

html2Canvasの　[DOMを画像に書き出す方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5851/dom%E3%82%92%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%81%AB%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%8D%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/5862#5862)　を参考にさせていただき、コードを書いたのですが、

スクリーンショットを撮るボタンを押しても、空の画像ファイルが生成されるだけです。
クリアボタンも効きません...。
私が、ターゲットとなるdivの中で、img srcにphp変数を使用しているからなのでしょうか？
しかしローカルファイルに置換してもダメでした。

```
    <div id="target_screen">
    <?php
        echo "<img class=\"effectedImage\" src=\"$image\">";
    ?>
</div>
```

テストとして、この画面下部にスクリーンショットを表示しようとしていますが、
最終的には、取得した画像を別のphpへpostしたいと考えています。

ご教授願います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTMLページと同じオリジン（由来、大抵ドメインで決まります）の画像を使用していますか？
Canvas要素に別オリジンの要素を描画した場合、そのCanvas要素の内容は取り出せなくなります。
セキュリティ上の制約です。
この制約がないと、本人しか閲覧できないはずの写真をJavaScriptで盗む、といった事が可能になるからです。

自分が所有しているサーバ同士であれば、同じオリジンとして扱う方法もあるようです。https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: ありがとうございます。
なるほど、、InstagramのAPIで取ってきた画像を使用しています。
それを、作成したPHP間で受け渡して使いまわしているのですが、
前のファイルで一度canvasとして扱ってしまうなどでは解決できませんよね・・・。
そのソースも結局は外部ですし。。
仮にそれができても、そのファイル自体の他に、そのファイルをテキストの形でclip(CSS)したdivタグなども出力したいので、私の知識では難しそうです。

Comment: 念の為確認しておきますが、画像ファイル自体にオリジンを証明するデータが含まれている分けではありません。ユーザがアクセスするのに使ったURLがオリジンを決定します。どこから取得した画像であれ、あなたのサーバからユーザに提供しているなら、オリジンはあなたのサーバになります。

Comment: 完全に勉強不足でした。
とすると、全て同じオリジンを使っています。
一度S3のCORS設定などから勉強してみたいと思います。

Comment: 画像の配信にS3のサーバを使われているのであれば、HTMLを提供しているサーバと別のドメインでしょうから、やはりオリジンが異なるという事です。S3のCORS設定を調べるという事ですので、ご理解なさっていると思いますが、念の為。

Comment: mjyさまには自分の無知を教えられるばかりで申し訳ないです。ご親切にありがとうございます。
行き当たりでS3を調べようとしていましたが、違いました......。御察しの通り、何から調べるべきかすら分かっていない状況です。

外部のオリジンから取得してきた画像を使っているわけではないですし、phpに原因があるのではと勝手に思っているので調べてみます。

Comment: PHPのコードでは無く、PHPが生成したHTMLを読むのが早いでしょう。HTMLページのURLと、imgタグのsrc属性のURLが、同じドメインであれば、同オリジンです。

Comment: そうですね、、コードを載せるにしても これだけで済みましたね。
`<div id="target_screen">
  <?php
   echo "<img class=\"effectedImage\" src=\"$image\" >";
   echo "<div id=\"clip\"><div class=\"texts\" id=\"fontsize\"><div class=\"texts\" id=\"fontweight\">$caption<br>";
   foreach((array)$obj->data as $item){
    $comment = $item->text;
   echo "$comment</br>";
   }
   echo "</div></div>";
   echo "</div>";
  ?>
</div>`

目的のページの２つ前のページでInstagramから画像を取得しているのですが、そのsrcを見たところ「value="ht*tps://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-****/t51.*****.jpg"」となっていたので、全く異なるオリジンでした。

Comment: PHPのコードでは無く、まず、PHPが生成したHTMLを読む必要があります。PHP上で$imageとなっていますが、これが実際にどう展開されているかが重要です。

Comment: 要素の検証で見たところ、src=\"$image\"がsrc="ht*tps://scontent.cdn‌​instagram.com/***~***"となっており、私が使っているのはhttp://p*****.php.xdomain.jp/ですので、やはり異なるオリジンでした...。

Comment: 原因が分かりましたね。よかったです。

Comment: 長々と本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: こちらは解決したのでしょうか？解決したのであれば解答の承認をお願いいたします。